# Ajax call returns undefined data

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an ajax call that requests data from an MVC controller method. 
I am returning a Json result from the controller.
Ajax request completes, but the data returned is undefined.
*Ajax Call*

```
var param = {
    "username": uname,
    "password": pass
};
var serviceURL = "/Account/CheckUser";

var req = $.ajax({
    url: serviceURL,
    type: "POST",

    data: JSON.stringify(param),

    contentType: "application/json",

    complete: successFunc,
    error: errorFunc
});

function successFunc(data) {
    if (data.exists == true) {
        console.log("Completed : " + data.exists);
    } else {
        console.log("Failed : " + data.exists);

    }
}
```

*Controller Method*

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult CheckUser(string uname, string pass)
{
    Boolean cont = true;
    return Json(new { exists = cont });
}
```

Can anyone tell me why `exists` returns as undefined? 
**UPDATE**

As suggested below, I wrote the data to the console, and it seems it's returning an empty string. So I guess the question should be more '**Why is the data returning empty?**

Comment: What does `console.log(data)` give you?

Comment: Check console.log(JSON.stringify(data)) or alert(JSON.stringify(data)) to see what you are getting. To check if you are really reaching CheckUser, put a break point in the start of the method to see exactly whats happening inside.

Comment: Or, better yet, add a `debugger;` in your function and learn to debug JavaScript in your browser.

Comment: @AndreiV: Don't even need `debugger;`, just open the debugger and set a breakpoint.

Comment: Side note: There's no reason to write `if (data.exists == true)`, just write `if (data.exists)`. I mean, if you don't trust the booleans, where do you stop? `if ((data.exists) == true) == true)`? `if (((data.exists) == true) == true) == true)`? :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that would also work, although, `debugger;` has it's own advantages (e.g. Visual Studio debugging when using IE, does not change the break point line after JS code lines have been added/removed -- Chrome does silly stuff sometimes...).

Comment: @AndreiV: The "silly" thing Chrome does for me is that it doesn't let me override a hardcoded `debugger;` statement (e.g., to turn it off because I don't need it for the moment). The good thing about real breakpoints is you can control them. Anyway, both have their place, I definitely use `debugger;` periodically...

Answer (score 2):

The function you specify via the `complete` option [doesn't receive the data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (for good reason: it's called even if there is no data, because there was an error). Change `complete:` to `success:`.

```
var req = $.ajax({
    url: serviceURL,
    type: "POST",

    data: JSON.stringify(param),

    contentType: "application/json",

    success: successFunc, // <=== Here
    error: errorFunc
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that's useful advice, however I'm still receiving undefined.

Comment: @piggy: Then you'll want to use the debugger in your browser: Inspect `data` and see what it is, look in the "Network" or "Net" tab to see the raw response from the server, etc., etc.

Comment: Under 'Response' in the network tab I get `"This request has no response data available" `